# Accidently renamed libc.so.6 and cannot chroot within rescue mode

Tags: libc, chroot, centos-6.9

We have accidently renamed shared library `/lib64/libc.so.6` to be `/lib64/libc.so_6`. Right after previous command the system (CentOS 6.9) throws the following error :

```
error while loading shared libraries: /lib64/libc.so.6: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
```

When logged in within rescue mode I followed the following commands :

```
mount /dev/md2 /mnt
mount /dev/md1 /mnt/boot
mount -t dev -o bind /dev /mnt/dev
mount -t proc -o bind /proc /mnt/proc
mount -t sys -o bind /sys /mnt/sys
chroot /mnt
</Code>
```

Then i get the following error :

```
/bin/bash: error while loading shared libraries: libc.so.6: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
```

I also tried the following commands :

```
chroot /mnt /bin/bash
chroot /mnt/root/tmp /bin/bash
chroot /mnt/root/tmp /mnt/bin/bash
```

Then get another error

```
chroot: failed to run command ‘/mnt/bin/bash’: No such file or directory
```

Now the system is down and I only have ssh which failed once "libc.so.6" renamed, and rescue mode. How could I enter to system so that i can rename "libc.so_6" back to "libc.so.6"? Is there a work-around to bypass checking for "libc.so_6"?

Comment: I don't know if it actually works, but have you tried booting into some other OS from live USB, mounting the FS with the corrupted .so and renaming it from there?

Comment: Can you try to renaming libc.so.6 back, without chroot?
e.g. `mv /mnt/lib64/libc.so_6 /mnt/lib64/libc.so.6`

Comment: Kuchara, 
many thanks brother, yes it worked, sorry i didnt slept well since three days, you solved my problem brother , many thanks again Kuchara

Comment: Welcome. By the way, first answer which came to my mind was: restore system from backup.

Comment: Be sure to accept the answer provided. ;)

Comment: Please read [Under what circumstances may I add “urgent” or other similar phrases to my question, in order to obtain faster answers?](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/326569) - the summary is that this is not an ideal way to address volunteers, and is probably counterproductive to obtaining answers. Please refrain from adding this to your questions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For the sake of clarity, will post the answer here (in case someone else encounter similar trouble).

When in rescue mode:

```
mount /dev/md2 /mnt
mv /mnt/lib64/libc.so_6 /mnt/lib64/libc.so.6
```

Alternatively:

- restore system from backup
- try booting from some live USB (as Topper Harley proposed in comments)